# Does a moving charge create current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge

If there is a moving charge, not in a circular path, but in a straight-line path, does it create current?
If it does, what is the relation between charge ($Q$), Velocity ($v$) and current ($I$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a moving charge always creates a current; but for a point charge it is not a constant current.

Imagine: if you only track a single position in space, the point charge (and thus current) is only there for an instant. Consider points in space spaced by a distance $d$ that our charge travels through:

```
o . . | . . no charge at | (t = -2 d/v)
. o . | . . no charge at | (t = -d/v)
. . . o . .    charge at | (t = 0)
. . . | o . no charge at | (t = d/v)
. . . | . o no charge at | (t = 2 d/v)
```

If we look at the current over time at the `|` point, we can model it with a Dirac delta: $I(t) = Q \cdot \delta(t)$.

You can integrate over this however you want to come up with an average current over some period of time, but it still stands that the charge $Q$ was only at `|` for an instant, and integrating our current function over time will always yield the total transmitted charge $Q$ if the integrated time period includes that instant of time (i.e. $t=0$), and yields a transmitted charge of $0$ otherwise. This is independent of the velocity, if we consider the `|` point alone.

For example, if you want to average the current of this point charge over time, you can select a region of space of length $d_s$ that you care about. If we average over just the time that the charge is in the space, then $I = Q \cdot v / d_s = Q / t_s$, where $t_s$ is the just the time our point charge was in the space. Note that if we choose to average over a longer period of time (in this case induced by choosing a longer region of space), the average current is necessarily reduced.

EDIT: For a distributed charge, rather than a point charge, see other answers.

Comment: Are you saying that there will be an instantaneous current on the point where the charge is passing ?

Comment: Yes, there will be. Depending on what you want to emphasize, you can always average the current some region of space or time to make this current non-instantaneous, though. What's really physical is that there is a point charge $Q$ moving with velocity $v$; the current $I$ is usually just a handy descriptor of the average behavior.

Comment: For each small sphere containing charge, there will be current just for the instant when it passes through this imaginary plane.There will be a maximum value of current for that instant. So, if there are infinite number of such spheres, and they were to cross this plane one by one with a constant velocity, there will be a constant current?

Comment: @ParamBudhadev If these spheres were infinitely space an close to each other, yes, the current would be constant! If we stop at one layer of the approximation--tiny spheres of charge $Q$ traveling at velocity $v$ spaced by a finite $d_s$ apart--the current is a periodic "Dirac delta train" function, and the time average of the current over a period is precisely what I already described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship is actually between charge density $\rho$, velocity $\vec v$, and current density $\vec j$. The relationship is exceptionally simple: $\vec j=\rho \vec v$

The charge density is the charge divided by the volume $\rho = Q/V$. The current density is the current divided by the cross sectional area $j=I/A$

Comment: So, if we multiply this by the area of cross section and the length, we can get the net current?

Comment: Just the cross sectional area, not the length. I will clarify in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have charge density $\rho$, you can write the current density $\vec{j}$ as

$$\vec{j} = \rho \vec{v}$$

where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of your particles.

The current can be computed from the current density with a surface integral. The idea is basically to integrate the current density over the cross-section of the conductor that is carrying your charged particles

$$I = \int_S \vec{j} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} = \int_S \rho \vec{v} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S}$$

If you have just one point-like particle it is not so easy to define the charge density $\rho$, because it will be a Dirac's delta.

#### Simple case

In the more common case for which you have $n$ particles (say electrons) per unit volume of equal charge $q$, you can define the charge density as $\rho = n q$. In this case the current density becomes $\vec{j} = \rho \vec{v}= n q \vec{v}$.

If the charge density is uniform on the surface considered for the integration, the integral above becomes

$$I = \int_S n q \vec{v} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} = n q \int_S \vec{v} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} = n q v A $$

where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the conductor (that is, the area perpendicular to velocity of the particles).

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to think of a sphere with a uniform *surface* charge density, $Q/4\pi r^2$ passing at constant speed, $v$, normally through an imaginary plane. The current through the plane will rise from zero to a constant value ($Qv/2r$) as soon as the sphere starts to cross through the plane. When it's finally through, the current will drop to zero. We can then consider smaller and smaller spheres, perhaps with equal charges on them. I'm led to the delta function as the limiting case.

Answer (score 0):

Q and I are linked by the equation I = Q/T. The current is how much charge passes through a point in the wire in one second.

If you bring velocity into this then you need to include distance. Speed = Distance/Time.

Rearranging these two give you T = D/S and T = Q/I.

Equating them gives you I=QxS/D or I=Qxv/D, the current is equal to the charge multiplied by the velocity divided by the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Electric current $i(t)$ through a surface is defined as the rate of charge transport through that surface, or

$$i(t)=\frac{dq(t)}{dt}$$

which is a function of time $t$ and $q(t)$ denotes the instantaneous charge. A constant current $i(t)$ is written as $I$ and the vector current density in amperes/m$^2$ is defined as $\vec J$.

The motion of charge that results in current is the collective motion of the charge in response to an electric field, called its drift velocity $v_d$. This is distinguished from any random thermal motion of the charge. The relationship between drift velocity $v_d$ and current $I$ is

$$I=\frac {Q}{t}=\frac {neAd}{d/v_{d}}=neAv_{d}$$

where

$n$ = number of charges $e$ per unit volume

$A$ = cross sectional area of the conductor.

$Q=neAd$ = total mobile charge in length $d$ of the conductor

$t=\frac{d}{v_d}$ = time for this charge to sweep past measuring point.

For the derivation of this equation and a microscopic view of electric current see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Hope this helps.